# How to delete a specific kernel?

Tags: kernel

I have installed a wrong version of the kernel. I want delete it because it is also visible from the grub advanced option.

Comment: There is already an answer to a similar question here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/89710/how-do-i-free-up-more-space-in-boot/270960#270960 Does that help?

Answer (score 2):

Let's explain it by using an example ... boot with the kernel you want to keep, in this case kernel `4.2.0-35`. 
To check which kernel versions currently are installed, open a terminal and execute :

```
dpkg --get-selections | grep linux
```

The output in this example shows that kernels `4.2.0-34` and `4.2.0-35` are currently installed.

```
linux-firmware                          install  
linux-generic                           install  
linux-headers-4.2.0-34                  install  
linux-headers-4.2.0-35                  install
linux-headers-4.2.0-34-generic          install
linux-headers-4.2.0-35-generic          install  
linux-headers-generic                   install  
linux-image-4.2.0-34-generic            install  
linux-image-4.2.0-35-generic            install
linux-image-extra-4.2.0-34-generic      install
linux-image-extra-4.2.0-35-generic      install  
linux-image-generic                     install  
linux-libc-dev:amd64                    install  
linux-signed-generic                    install  
linux-signed-image-4.2.0-34-generic     install  
linux-signed-image-4.2.0-35-generic     install
linux-signed-image-generic              install
```

Assuming that the older `kernel 4.2.0-34` shall be removed - execute the following command :

```
sudo apt-get purge linux-headers-4.2.0-34 linux-headers-4.2.0-34-generic linux-image-4.2.0-34-generic linux-image-extra-4.2.0-34-generic linux-signed-image-4.2.0-34-generic
```

## Done! :-)

Comment: FYI: Unless you carefully address the above, you can end up deleting other critical things.  As cl-netbox did here, they selectively found and specified the packages they want to delete - do NOT delete the entire list of results from the `dpkg --get-selections` blindly!

Comment: I had some challenges to run the command as installation of some kernels where not complete due to running out of space on /boot volume. The solution for me was to increase /boot size, then complete kernel installation by running "apt-get -f install" and than applying @cl-netbox recommendation.